# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried everything that has been told in Stackoverflow topics. I have java selenium tests run on remote slave through jenkins. The absurd thing is ******first** test** always run** and browsers opens, all other tests give me "Timed out waiting for driver server to start".

```
public WebDriver startChrome() {
            
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
    prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--aggressive-cache-discard"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-cache"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-application-cache"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-offline-load-stale-cache"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disk-cache-size=0");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-proxy-server"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--log-level=3"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--silent"); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
    chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL); 
    chromeOptions.addArguments("-disable-cache");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("-disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--incognito");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
    //chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
    port = chromeDriverService.getUrl().getPort();
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: 'de8579b6d5'
System info: host: 'ISTDTSTYNMD04V', ip: '10.52.253.54', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_271'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.lambda$start$0(DriverService.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1596)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:35592/status] to be available after 20000 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:227)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:88)
    ... 8 more
```

All the solutions I have tried so far:

- Update Java 1_8_271
- Update Selenium 4
- Update ChromeDriver 87
- Check localhost traffic with rawcap
- Check localhost dns definiton in etc/hosts
- Update Chrome 87
- Set Proxy
- Check port availability
- Check driver path
- Kill all chrome and driver tasks before create (Only solution that worked, but not good for parallel tests)
- Check localhost url and port is accessible with chrome -> http 200

When I try to reach url and port through java urlconnection in code driver create function catch block), it gives me connection reset but in chrome it gives 200.

All help will be appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. 
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: 'de8579b6d5' 
System info: host: 'ISTDTSTYNMD04V', ip: '10.52.253.54', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_271' 
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

A bit of more information about your usecase would have helped us to analyze the error in a better way. However to start with you can use only one single arguments `start-maximized` and remove all the other arguments which would get you started. So your effective code block will be:

```
public WebDriver startChrome() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
    ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
}
```

### Additional Consideration

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u271](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v87.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 87.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v87.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt)).
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium Chromedriver server times out despite being available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821298/selenium-chromedriver-server-times-out-despite-being-available/47845434#47845434)
- [Driver info: driver.version: unknown with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266021/unknownerror-timed-out-waiting-for-driver-server-to-start-and-driver-info-driv/59268115#59268115)
- [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start while initiating Chrome browser through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058844/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-timed-out-waiting-for-driver-server-to-s/55059339#55059339)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, a lot. I have tried before and tried again after your help everything you have described but no luck. Firewall is off. driver.quit always runs in @AfterTest. jdk is updated. chrome and drivers are updated. couple of reboots.Executed as root and non-root user. But I couldn't try checking web client version. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi, Just tested same code in datacenter 2019 virtual machien and it worked. The other machine I was trying before has datacenter 2016. Do you think these are related?

Comment: @Eymasar There can be numerous different aspects to look in between the two distinct systems _Datacenter 2019 virtual machine_ and _Datacenter 2016_. Ideally you must always keep the testbed separate from daily development tweaks